# Invoke action of core Liferay's portlet (Document Library) using custom portlet's form

Tags: liferay

I need to call document library portlet's `EditFileEntryAction` (core liferay) on submitting my custom form.

I have created following actionURL:

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="editFileEntryURL" portletName="<%=PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY %>" doAsGroupId="${scopeGroupId}" refererPlid="${plid}">
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" />
    <portlet:param name="uploader" value="classic" />
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
```

and I want to submit below form:

```
<aui:form action="<%= editFileEntryURL %>" cssClass="lfr-dynamic-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fm">
    <aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden" />
    <aui:input name="uploadProgressId" type="hidden" value="<%= uploadProgressId %>" />
    <aui:input name="repositoryId" type="hidden" value="${themeDisplay.scopeGroupId}" />
    <aui:input name="folderId" type="hidden" value="${categoryFolderId}" />
    <aui:input name="fileEntryId" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <aui:input name="workflowAction" type="hidden" value="<%= WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH %>" />

    <aui:input name="file" style="width: auto;" type="file">
        <aui:validator name="acceptFiles">
            '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>'
        </aui:validator>
    </aui:input>

    <aui:input name="title">
        <aui:validator errorMessage="you-must-specify-a-file-or-a-title" name="custom">
            function(val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {`enter code here`
                return ((val != '') || A.one('#<portlet:namespace />file').val() != '');
            }
        </aui:validator>
    </aui:input>

    <aui:button type="submit" value="save" name="save" />
</aui:form>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL being created?

Comment: URL being created : http://localhost:8080/group/myisover/cctp?p_auth=0IuA14Jb&p_p_auth=n0XBP6RC&p_p_id=20&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&doAsGroupId=14811&refererPlid=14843&_20_struts_action=%2Fdocument_library%2Fedit_file_entry&_20_uploader=classic

Comment: Have you verified using debugger, does it hit `processAction` method of `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction`?

Comment: Not hitting processAction method of com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction

Comment: If yes, it means URL is good, but you also need to pass additional parameters like, `cmd` as `Constants.EDIT`, `fileEntryId` as `0`, `folderId` as `0` to upload file at root.

Comment: Is there any mistake in my code or can we use core liferay portlet's action url to submit the custom form ?

Comment: I am passing parameters like, cmd, fileEntryId, folderId as hidden variables in form.

Comment: Ok, share your complete form then.

Comment: Have you tried debugging, does it hit when `EditFileEntryAction`, when you submit form?

Comment: Yes..its not calling EditFileEntryAction

Comment: Change your `<aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden" />` to `<aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden"  value="<%= Constants.EDIT %>" />`. Thus, it will identify that, it has to call `updateFileEntry` using `processAction`.

Comment: Already tried that solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to *not* have the HTTP-level cross-dependency on Liferay's document library portlet. Rather implement your own upload portlet and use the document library API to store the file yourself.